# Вопрос на счёт функций

Tags: php, функции

Хочу написать скрипт, который будет работать с базой данных. Но у меня возникли проблемы с реализацией функций.

Мне так кажется, что они не дожидаются завершения, а вызываются сразу, по очереди.

Этот скрипт не работает.

```
    <?php
include_once "connect_bd.php";

$mArrayListData = array();
$query = null;

function connectBD(){
  $query = ("SELECT * FROM `articles_common` WHERE `title_original` != 'null' ORDER BY `_id` DESC");
}

function addDataArray(){
  $ta = mysqli_query(getConnection(), $query);
  $size_bd = mysqli_num_rows( $ta );

  if($size_bd != 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ta)){ 

      $row_array['_id'] = $row['_id'];
      $row_array['title_original'] = $row['title_original'];
      array_push($mArrayListData, $row_array);

    }
  } else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ta)){ 
      array_push($mArrayListData, $row_array);
    }
  }

    print_r(count($mArrayListData));
}

function start(){
    connectBD();
    addDataArray();
}

start();
```

Но работает вот такой вариант.

```
function addDataArray(){
$mArrayListData = array();
$query = ("SELECT * FROM `articles_common` WHERE `title_original` != 'null' ORDER BY `_id` DESC");
  $ta = mysqli_query(getConnection(), $query);
  $size_bd = mysqli_num_rows( $ta );

  if($size_bd != 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ta)){

      $row_array['_id'] = $row['_id'];
      $row_array['title_original'] = $row['title_original'];
      array_push($mArrayListData, $row_array);

    }
  } else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ta)){ 
      array_push($mArrayListData, $row_array);
    }
  }

    print_r(count($mArrayListData));
}
```

Comment: Вы понимаете что функция addDataArray в первом варианте вообще не знает о существовании переменной query?

Comment: Она же глобальная, и объявлена в начале.

Comment: Обратитесь к мануалам по области видимости переменных.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял.

Comment: Вы можете описать решение проблемы в ответе, чтобы я его принял.